# Live Video Broadcasting In Android

Tags: android, video, webrtc, android-broadcast

Hi I am working on app in which I need to broadcast live video on Facebook and YouTube. All I came to know that Facebook and YouTube provides `RTMP URL`.

Now i need to pass that `RTMP URL` to a `webRTC` client. [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/#running-the-apprtcmobile-app) official site says that -

> Running the AppRTCMobile App AppRTCMobile is an Android application
>   using WebRTC Native APIs via JNI (JNI wrapper is documented here).

.For JNI i need to include NDK which will make app heavy. Is webRTC only way? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you know that you should not ask for a library here, right?

Comment: @Vladyav I updated my question. Please don’t demotivate me by Dow voting my question. I am new here with hope of some help

Comment: there is nothing to do with your motivation. It's only StackOverflow rules, which you don't care about. A question rating is only to show the quality of the question, nothing personal.

Comment: Also nothing changed in your question in fact: you show no attempt from your side, and still want the library.

Comment: WebRTC doesn't need  NDK. You can use prebuilt google libraries.

Comment: So what should I do ? Where should I go for help ? I updated my question did you see ? I am just asking if anyone know webRTC alternative that is open source  there are a lot of questions like that on stack sites with good votes

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` - from the question close reasons. `So what should I do ?` if it was me, I'd do the research of how to use webRTC, or checking the facebook and youtube API for the way to life-stream.

Comment: @Vladyslav can you please edit it for me ? How can I show my efforts here ? Do I need to write whole thing in long what I did in R&D  ? What I tried

Comment: I can't edit it as i don't know what you already done. You should describe in short what you tried, and also why exactly you are unable to do that (integrate with facebook & youtube, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently worked on a project with same requirements I integrate below project -

- [**LiveVideoBroadcaster**](https://github.com/ant-media/LiveVideoBroadcaster).

  It's free and OpenSource active on **GitHub**. All you need is to provide RTMP url which you will get from Facebook/YouTube.

For Facebook refer [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/) and for YouTube refer [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started).

Comment: answerring off-topic questions is not helping stackoverflow community. As well as posting link-only answers.

Comment: @karanatwal I have tested this LiveVideoBroadcaster for RTMP URLs and it worked but it doesn't work for RTMPS URLs. Do you have any idea to make it work for RTMPS as well?

Comment: @abdul i have'nt tested it on RTMPS . I will let you know on weekdays. In the meantime if you are getting issue you can post issue on their github page.